# Boolean Jquery While/If

Tags: jquery, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

Sorry for the question but i am bad in jquery.

I created a menu on my website which is openable with a click, and i want while/if this menu is opened that the opacity is 0.

I created a variable

```
var IsOpened = false; //bool
```

and in my function:

```
$('#sidebar-menu, #overlay').click(function() {
    $('.portfolio-full').removeClass('portfolio-open');
    $('#top').removeClass('portfolio-open');
    $('#sidebar-button').toggleClass('open');
    $('#sidebar-menu').toggleClass('open');
    $('body').toggleClass('sidebar-open');
    IsOpened = true;
    return false;
});
```

and after this code i put:

```
if (IsOpened = true) {
    $('#top').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},400);
}
```

or

```
while (IsOpened = true) {
    $('#top').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},400);
}
```

but this is not working, why?

Comment: `=` is not a comparison operator `==`. If you just write `if(IsOpened)`  it would work

Comment: IsOpened should really be isOpened

Comment: Thank you it works with the if, but with the while no :(

Comment: How to make it works for a while, because with a if when i close the sidebar it stay opacity : 0 :/

Answer (score 0):

You should use '===' instead of '=', the '=' is assign operator.

Then put `$('#top').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},400);` in your `.click()` function body.

Comment: How to make it works for a while, because with a if when i close the sidebar it stay opacity : 0 :/

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct, you are using the assignment operator `=` in your conditions, but...

If you are removing/adding classes to elements on click with JQuery anyway, why not use CSS classes to apply the opacity transition?

Then you don't need the Boolean variable or the check, and you've moved some 'presentation' concerns away from your code.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Yes i know, thank you for your answer, i simplify the story here, it's a little more complicated ^^ but thank you ! :)